# "Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)." when updating table

Tags: java, mysql

I need help with a final project I'm making for college, I'm making a Library kind of System. I'm new to mySQL.

> I'm having a problem on code saying, "Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)."

```
PreparedStatement book_edit = book_db.prepareStatement("update books set ?='?' where id=?");

            book_edit.setString(1, column); //where column is to set the column of the table
            book_edit.setString(2, input); //where input is what you want to change
            book_edit.setInt(3, book_id); //the primary key in my database

            int i = book_edit.executeUpdate();

            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println("UPDATED!!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Failed to Add Data!");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column name cannot be a variable of the `PreparedStatement`. It must be part of the SQL `String`:

```
PreparedStatement book_edit = book_db.prepareStatement("update books set " + column + "= ? where id = ?");

book_edit.setString(1, input); //where input is what you want to change
book_edit.setInt(2, book_id); //the primary key in my database
```

Comment: Oh no, I still get the same error but instead of 3 > number of parameters, which is 2. I get 2 > num of parameters, which is 1

Comment: @RioAblas Are you sure you are setting only the parameters indexed 1 and 2? If you do, you can't be getting the same error (of `3 > number of parameters`), since you are not setting 3 parameters.

Comment: I followed your code and erased my first set.String (which was "1,column"). and if I remove the single quotation marks after the 
`+ column + "=` I get an error saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: @RioAblas did you change the indices of the remaining `setX()` calls from 2 to 1 and from 3 to 2?

Comment: yes I did exactly what you said.
`book_edit.setString(1, provider);
 book_edit.setInt(2, book_id);`

Comment: @RioAblas well, I don't think it should make a difference, but perhaps there should be a space between the = and the ? (see edit)

Comment: I got it now, the answer you provided fixed it. the mistake I had was that the update statement from my SQL server was different from the update statement I have in my java.

Before:
`update books set " + column + "= ? where id = ?`

Now:
`UPDATE library.books SET "+ column +" = ? WHERE (book_id = ?)`

the error said that the code I had before was for an older version.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna make this the answer!